# Whats in a title?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

As a member of the executive board for my local camera club, we were standardizing the titles for consistency and uniformity.

Previously, Vice President of Competition and Vice President of Programs were not consistently named and caused confusion.

In some places it was Vice-President vs. Vice President and in others it was 'for Competitions' vs. 'of Competition' as well as 'of Programs' vs. 'for Programs'.

Is there an appropriate way to specify this?

Comment: A vice president by any other name..

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using *"Vice President"* anyway. Normally an organisation has at most *one* President, and *one* VP. The others are usually *Directors*. If you have a Board of Directors who mostly aren't involved in the day-to-day matters (and if they're not already called a Board of Governors) your "departmental head honchos" can just be called *Head of XXX*.

Answer (score 1):

I’d keep the hyphen. You can avoid prepositions altogether with ‘Competitions Vice-President’ and ‘Programs Vice-President’. Alternatively ‘Vice-President (Competitions)’ and ‘Vice-President (Programs)’.